# Run Multiple methods for each value of DataProvider in TestNG

Tags: java, automation, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a bunch of TestNG tests that run using a DataProvider as a bunch of parameters.

My Runner looks something like this:

```
   <methods>
     <include name="test1">
     <include name="test2">
   </methods>
```

So lets say if i have two parameters (param1 and param2) from the Dataprovider, the test executes in the following sequence:

```
test1 with param1
test1 with param2
test2 with param1
test2 with param2
```

Is there a way to make it run all test cases per parameter. i.e., the execution should be as follows:

test1 with param1
   test2 with param1
   test1 with param2
   test2 with param2

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need 2 data providers..  makes you program better to understand and easier to expand...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide a little more details? I'm not sure how a second Data Provider should be implemented in this scenario

Comment: One way to do it would be.. make 2 different excel sheets for 2 different value sets.. and in your single data provider you can keep a static variable which says if(count ==1 or count==2) read from sheet1 , elseif (count ==3 or count ==4) read from sheet 2.. something like this...